# AWS RDS Postgres cross-account replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, rds

Is it possible to set up cross-account replication with the AWS RDS Postgres database? The goal is to have a read-only replica in a separate AWS account.

I know it's somewhat possible to accomplish with DMS, but I want to avoid that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, cross account replica is not supported by RDS, according to AWS support.

Have you resolved your issue btw? I've been looking for delayed replication for disaster recovery purposes, like described in [Gitlab article](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/02/13/delayed-replication-for-disaster-recovery-with-postgresql/) and looks like such scenario is not supported by RDS at all.

Comment: No, I was not able to find a solution. The best thing to do for my case is to take regular snapshots and move them to a separate account instead of real-time replication.

Comment: @martin49 same here, I've opened a [new question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1001561/aws-rds-disaster-recovery-using-cross-account) about this topic

Answer (score 0):

just saw this...
(i have not tried it)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html